# Contact Form 7 404 [contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Not appear contact form.
try inserting it as shorcode in post/page:

```
[contact-form-7 id="8791" title="test"]
```

also insert as PHP:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="8792" title="test2"]' ); ?>
```

already try removing all the plugins, also try changing permalinks

[image: 404 Not Found]

and still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you check if the id exist in the db ?

Comment: Not appear in the database

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, First I'm using WPBackery Page Builder then access form page, edit, select your form and viola. It will appears. I don't know but some how its works. I think its a kind of bug. Using WPBackery Page like refresh link between your page and your form.